# When is a matrix a constant multiple of unit matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How can it be proved that if a matrix has all eigenvalues equal and it's eigenvectors form a complete set, then the matrix is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix?

What happens if the eigenvectors do not form a complete set?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by a complete set?

Comment: @KennyLau It spans the entire space. As for when the eigenvectors do not form a complete set, see $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ for an example.

Comment: @Arthur I was asking the Author for clarification...

Comment: @KennyLau And you got a clarification from me. For the time being you will have to make do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix $M$ has repeated eigenvalue $\lambda$, and is diagonalizable, hence the Jordan form is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda\\&\lambda\\&&\ddots\\&&&\lambda\end{bmatrix}=PMP^{-1},$$
for some invertible $P$.

Hence $$PMP^{-1}=\lambda I\implies PM=\lambda I P$$$$ \implies M = P^{-1}\lambda I P= \lambda I P^{-1}P = \lambda I,$$
as required.

Answer (score 1):

For part 1: if eigenvectors $v_1, v_2$ of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ share an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then so do all linear combinations of $v_1, v_2$:
$$
A(a_1v_1 + a_2v_2) = a_1A(v_1) + a_2A(v_2) = a_1\lambda v_1 + a_2 \lambda v_2 = \lambda (a_1v_1 + a_2v_2).
$$
Thus, if $A$ has a set of eigenvectors sharing an eigenvalue $\lambda$ which span the whole space, then in fact every vector of the space is an eigenvector. In particular, this is true for the standard basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$. Now note that the $i$th column of $A$ is equal to $Ae_i$, and
$$
Ae_i = \lambda e_i,
$$
so that $A = \lambda I_n$.

For the second part: hint, consider the matrix
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Also, for any invertible matrix $P$, consider $PBP^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If a matrix $A$ has all eigenvalues equal, it means that the characteristic polynomial of the matrix is $p_A(t)=(t-\lambda)^n$.
Considering that $\dim(V)=n$ and that all the eigenvectors span all the space, you can say that $rk(A-\lambda I)=0$ which implies the matrix has $n$ blocks in its Jordan Normal Form. It easily follows that it is diagonalizable and, by having all the eigenvalues equal, it is a multiple of the identity.

Edit:
If all the eigenvectors do not span all the space, you have $rk(A-\lambda I)=k >0$ which implies that the Jordan Normal Form of the matrix has less then $n$ blocks, so it is not diagonalizable.

Example: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over a field $F$. Let the matrix be $A$ and its eigenvalue be $\lambda$.

By the assumption, we have $A \vec v = \lambda \vec v$ for all $\vec v \in V$.

Substituting $\vec v = \vec e_i$, one gets $A\vec e_i = \lambda \vec e_i$ where $\{\vec e_1, \vec e_2, \cdots, \vec e_n\}$ is the standard basis of $V$.

Then:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
AI_n &=& A[\vec e_1~\vec e_2~\cdots~\vec e_n]\\
&=& [A\vec e_1~A\vec e_2~\cdots~A\vec e_n]\\
&=& [\lambda \vec e_1~\lambda \vec e_2~\cdots~\lambda \vec e_n]\\
&=& \lambda [\vec e_1~\vec e_2~\cdots~\vec e_n]\\
&=& \lambda I_n
\end{array}$$

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the eigenvectors of the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ span the whole space $K^n$ (where $K$ is the base field) if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable.